# When an iron core is placed in a solenoid, why does the current increase?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, inductance

Does the flux of the coil cut the soft iron core and generate emf in it? I am confused over the fact that since a stronger magnetic field, shouldn't the current increase. I believe the decrease in current has something to do with back emf and self inductance but I don't completely understand that. Is there any affect by dc or ac supply?
Edit : Sorry about the unclarity of this question as I don't know much about the topic, I have studied it in only Layman's Terms. (A level physics to be precise)

Comment: The question is horribly unclear. I guess it is about AC?

Comment: Increase or decrease?

Answer (score 1):

An iron core placed in a current carrying solenoid will be magnetized, and will contribute its field to that of the solenoid.  This process will produce a momentary changing flux of field through the coil which will induce a voltage in the coil which tends to oppose the change in flux.  If the coil is driven by an AC source, this opposing voltage will also alternate and limit the current in the coil. This effect is referred to as the “self inductance” of the solenoid (with a core).